How do I publish my website built by Google Sites?
I have problems to publish a website (Google Sites). I have added Cname and A Records (external hosing Miss Hosting). Doesnt work... Any ideas? Thx
Added Cname and A Records from Google Sites. I have seareched for oth and found them, but still doesnt work. What have I missed?`
